# Runtime Error When Pulling Ultralytic Model from TorchHub Using YOLOV5

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, yolov5

I'm new to ML and PyTorch (and using a M1 Mac for context) and followed the three instructions listed on [`the YOLOV5 GitHub Page`](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5), but I run into an issue when trying to pull the yolov5s model from torch.hub and it tells me a Runtime Error occured and "It looks like there is no internet connection and the repo could not be found in the cache (/Users/myaccount/.cache/torch/hub)". I am definitely connected to the internet and the cache folder I found at the directory it's trying to access is empty (even when showing all hidden folders/files).

The file consists of the following and I tried running it with and without the pretrained parameter:

```
import torch

model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s', pretrained=True)
```

I always get a bunch of traceback errors starting from line 6 and the last error print out is
`RuntimeError: It looks like there is no internet connection and the repo could not be found in the cache (/Users/myaccount/.cache/torch/hub)`

Comment: Fixed it by adding a SSL certificate: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/33288#issuecomment-954160699